# How to bridge multiple adsl router in a single network?

Tags: networking, router, internet, bridge, adsl-router

I have two extra adsl router(SSID named as **0** and **1**) and a main router(SSID named as **2**) provided by my ISP.

Now I want to extend my internet connection via wifi or lan using those two adsl router.

I have configured both the **0** and **1** (router) for bridging; settings like, changing the ip(**0**'s ip changed to 192.168.150.100 and **1**'s ip is changed to 192.168.250.100)=>disable dhcp setting,etc.

The thing is, after I configured these setting, if I use them one at a time, then the internet works perfectly, but when I join **0** and **1** both of them to the main router(**2**), it stops working after some times.

If I reboot the main router, it starts to work again for some time and stops again.

What could be the reason? Is this because of IP conflict between **0** and **1**? Please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have one ISP (you said that above) and so one External IP address then connect additional routers to the main router as follows:

Connect a LAN port on a Router to a LAN port on your network.

Give the added router a Static IP address on the network (to prevent changes when you restart things).

Turn DHCP OFF on the added Router and now it will be an extension of your main network and you will no longer have these conflicts.

Comment: Creating a bridge for single router is not the problem, I have already done

If I connect single secondary router then it works but when I connect multiple secondary router then it stops working.

If you can check the question one more time, I think i have explained clearly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can easily connect two routers to the same network as I said above.  Just make sure you have different IP addresses for each router on the main network. That is what you said above  (when I join 0 and 1 both of them to the main router(2) ) . So long as DHCP is Off and you connected LAN to LAN it will work

Comment: Just to underscore - make sure DHCP is OFF on both routers.  Extra DHCP servers can easily cause issues

Comment: Did you get connection stability after removing duplicate DHCP servers?